# How to prevent hourglass on cursor during load times in Electron app?

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

For example, when calling `webview.loadURL()`, the cursor will *always* show the hourglass icon momentarily, no matter how small the page is. Even for local files, even for 'about:blank'.

In Chrome and other browsers, the spinner in the upper-left next to backwards and forwards navigation will indicate a page is loading, instead of showing it on the mouse.

I'd like to use my own in-page spinner to indicate loading, and keep the mouse cursor to default, what can I do to prevent the hourglass cursor when loading a page?

Edit: OS is Windows 10, although I'd imagine the same thing happens in any OS. To reproduce, simply update a `webview` using `webview.src = "example.com"` or `webview.loadURL("example.com")`.

Comment: It would help to post a screenshot of the window with the cursor, a minimal example that will allow us to reproduce this, and perhaps your OS.

Comment: Oh I think I misread - it's just a Windows "busy" cursor I take it

Comment: Yep exactly. I've updated the post to explain how to reproduce it, however there's surely many ways to trigger the "busy" cursor, this is just one of them.

Comment: off the top of my head, you'd do something like this by setting the `cursor` CSS property to `default` or whatever you need, and creating a class that's set on, say, your `body` that applies that styling. I haven't had much success with it though if I'm being honest. Possibly related to [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1222) issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't get this to work either unfortunately. Still searching for a solution